# window handle in MFC?

Tags: mfc

how to get window handle in MFC??

Comment: Need a little more information here mate.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: so give him a check, since he is right ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's the [m_hWnd](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zwdbkfhc(VS.80).aspx) member of your CWnd.

Answer (score 8):

CWnd::GetSafeHwnd is a little "safer" because it can be used with a NULL CWnd pointer
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/d64ehwhz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Use `CWnd::GetSafeHwnd()` to get the `HWND` from a `CWnd` object; use `CWnd::FromHandle` to bind a `HWND` to a temporary `CWnd` object.

Answer (score 1):

Access the `m_hWnd` member of your `CWnd`, like this:

```
HWND Handle = this->m_hWnd
```

Comment: Please provide some explanation.

Comment: Provide more context please

Comment: The same as the accepted answer. The difference is the accepted one is upvoted and this one is downvoted ( ^ ^ )

Answer (score 1):

There are two methodes:
First one, you can use the `m_hWnd` member variable of your `CWnd` class to get the window handle.

If you want get the other window's handle, you can use  `FindWindow` windows API. like this:

```
HANDLE hWind = FindWindow( your_win_class_name, your_win_name );
```

Answer (score 0):

to use "getsafeHwnd" function, you must c before you use the return value

Comment: Please give the solution with some code snippet for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

HANDLE hwnd =FindWindowW( __in_opt LPCWSTR lpClassName,__in_opt LPCWSTR lpWindowName);

first one is class name "Button" or "Edit control"
second one is window name.Handler of the window (m_hWnd).