# get handle of window

Tags: c++, mfc, window, handle

I have a window which runs in separate thread. I need to get the handle of that window in another thread.

I can't use ::FindWindow API, because the window name will change, as my application can run in other languages. Plus, I don't have access to the resource string used for window name.

I can't use ::GetActiveWindow also, as the calling thread id and the active window thread id is different.

Please suggest some solution.

Comment: [`GetGUIThreadInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633506(v=vs.85).aspx) would seem a reasonable choice, assuming you have the id of of your prospect thread.

Comment: Why you need to search for it if you   created it yourself . [window handle in mfc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255207/window-handle-in-mfc).

Comment: The window is not created by myself. It belongs to a different ocx. I need its handle in my ocx. Both the ocx run under same process. How do I get the thread id of the window.

Comment: so you neither know threadid or anything related to that window to distinguish. Check your applicaiton with spy++ tool. it might be helpfull

Comment: Given a pointer to the OLE control, QI for `IOleWindow`, then use `IOleWindow::GetWindow` to get the window handle.

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to pass the window name to the FindWindow function. You can pass NULL for the window name and find the window using only the lpClassName parameter.

MFC normally assigns window class names automatically, but you can control a window's class name by registering a unique name with AfxRegisterClass and creating the window with that registered class name.